# How can text be used for multiple regex matches (Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am trying to read a file that has the following structure.

```
Question 1 What is the weather today? Answer 1 It is hot and sunny. Question 2 What day is it today? Answer 2 Thursday Question 3 How many legs does a dog have? Answer 3 Four legs
```

I want to put the content in a dictionary with questions and answers, so something like this:

```
dict = {
  "What is the weather today?": "It is hot and sunny.",
  "What day is it today?": "Thursday",
  "How many legs does a dog have?": "Four legs"
}
```

To find the questions and answers in the text, I created this regular expression:

```
\s?(Question|Answer)\s\d+\s?(.*)\s?(Question|Answer)\s\d+\s?
```

You also can find the regex with the example [here](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5Cs%3F(Question%7CAnswer)%5Cs%5Cd%2B%5Cs%3F(.*)%5Cs%3F(Question%7CAnswer)%5Cs%5Cd%2B%5Cs%3F&test_string=%20%20%20%20Question%201%20What%20is%20the%20weather%20today%3F%20Answer%201%20It%20is%20hot%20and%20sunny.%20Question%202%20What%20day%20is%20it%20today%3F%20Answer%202%20Thursday%20Question%203%20How%20many%20legs%20does%20a%20dog%20have%3F%20Answer%203%20Four%20legs&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0). As you can see on that page, it finds one big match, instead of multiple smaller matches. I assume that you need the `Question` and `Answer` texts for two matches, because `Question 2`, for example, means both the end of the match of `Answer 1`, and the start of the match of `Question 2`.  How can I get the questions and the answers itself correctly, so that I can put it in a dictionary (including the last answer, after which no new 'Question X' follows), as shown in the example dictionary?

Comment: You could use `\bQuestion\s\d+\s+(\S.*?)\s+Answer\s+\d+\s+(\S.*?)\s*(?=Question|$)` to get the groups https://regex101.com/r/iksBgQ/1

Answer (score 2):

If there is a question followed by an answer, you don't have to use the alternation `|`, but you can first match `Question` and then match `Answer`

```
\bQuestion\s+\d+\s+(\S.*?)\s+Answer\s+\d+\s+(\S.*?)\s*(?=Question|$)
```

- `\bQuestion\s+\d+\s+` Match `Question` followed by 1+ digits between whitespace chars
- `(\S.*?)` Capture **group 1**, match at least a single non whitespace char
- `\s+Answer\s+\d+\s+` Match `Answer` followed by 1+ digits between whitespace chars
- `(\S.*?)` Capture **group 2**, match at least a single non whitespace char
- `\s*(?=Question|$)` Match optional whitespace char asserting either another question to the right or the end of the string in case of the last question

Then you could for example use [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) to get the group 1 and group 2 values and fill a dictionary.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UJQnUh/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/QTRMkk)

```
import re

dict = {}

regex = r"\bQuestion\s+\d+\s+(\S.*?)\s+Answer\s+\d+\s+(\S.*?)\s*(?=Question|$)"
s = "Question 1 What is the weather today? Answer 1 It is hot and sunny. Question 2 What day is it today? Answer 2 Thursday Question 3 How many legs does a dog have? Answer 3 Four legs"

for m in re.findall(regex, s):
    dict[m[0]] = m[1]
print(dict)
```

Output

```
{'What is the weather today?': 'It is hot and sunny.', 'What day is it today?': 'Thursday', 'How many legs does a dog have?': 'Four legs'}
```